# Oracle number value issue

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert the value 1234567.1234 on NUMBER(21,12) in my oracle 19c.
The number inserted is 1234567.123399999920 instead of 1234567.123400000000.
Is it possible to avoid this behavior without updating the number precision and scale?
Thanks!

Comment: Am not an Oracle expert, but guess that you'd be better off using DECIMAL instead of NUMBER to get exact precision.

Comment: Aha.  Maybe the problem is in the programming language sending the value to the dB?  E.G. In C# a 'double' may exhibit this lack of precision, whereas a 'decimal' will not.

Comment: Hi Neil W, thanks for your feedback.I have the same issue when I launch the insert query on PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Fair enough.  Am still suspicious of NUMBER vs DECIMAL.  Am happy to bow to Austin's greater knowledge of Oracle, but my general experience in this area is that, when these type of weird decimal place rounding issues happen, then it is normally because the datatype (e.g. double in C#) is using a binary representation that cannot represent every possible decimal value.  The C# decimal datatype uses a different (slower and more memory hogging approach) to store the value ... but it does provide absolute accuracy.  If a NUMBER includes decimals, then what value does a DECIMAL give you in Oracle?

Comment: @NeilW [`DECIMAL[(p,s)]`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213) is an alias for `NUMBER(p,s)`. The `NUMBER`  data type stores values exactly with each byte representing two digits of the number. You are correct that the issue is probably due to being stored as a binary representation but it is not an issue with how Oracle stores the value; it is probably related to how the value was inserted into the table.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DUMP(column_name) FROM your_table` and what was the DML statement that you used to insert the data?

Comment: Hi MTO,thanks for your feedback.The DUMP value is Typ=2 Len=7: 196,2,24,46,68,13,35

Answer (score 0):

Well could you support your claim with some *evidence*? I.e. the tools you use for insert etc. Most probably it is not a *database problem*.

Here is an *Counterbeispiel*:

```
create table test (col  NUMBER(21,12) ); 

insert into test (col) values (1234567.1234);

select to_char(col,'9999999.9999999') col, dump(col) dmp from test;

COL              DMP                                     
---------------- ----------------------------------------
 1234567.1234000 Typ=2 Len=7: 196,2,24,46,68,13,35
```

Comment: This is a solution for the select number display but not for the insert number value: suppose we have two tables test and test1 and both tables have a column col number(21.12) when I try to insert the value 1234567.1234 on table test on column col and then insert the same value of test.col on test1.col the value inserted is1234567.12399999920 even when I use to_char for test.col.

Comment: Well my point was @user3621399 - post your script and show the result. My dump is the same as yours.

Comment: create table test1 (col  NUMBER(21,12) ); 
create table test2 (col  NUMBER(21,12) ); 
insert into test1 (col) values (1234567.1234);
insert into test2 select to_char(col,'9999999.9999999') from test1;
select * from test2;
Result:
COL
1234567,123399999920

Comment: The script returns `ORA-01722: invalid number`  because of storing result of `to_char` in a `number` column. Why do you convert to char at all? This is the probably cause @user3621399 Try with `insert into test2(col) select col from test1; ` which works fine.

Comment: Both insert queries return the same result on my side:
insert into test2 select to_char(col,'9999999.9999999') from test1;
insert into test2(col) select col from test1;
select * from test2;
Result: 
COL
1234567,123399999920
1234567,123399999920

Comment: I tried all these queries
insert into test1(col) values (to_char(1234567.1234,'9999999.9999'));
insert into test1(col) values (substr(to_char(1234567.1234,'9999999.9999'),0,13));
insert into test1(col) values (to_number(1234567.1234,'9999999.9999'));
insert into test1(col) values (cast(1234567.1234 as number(11,4)));
insert into test1(col) values (1234567.123400000000);insert into test1(col) values (round(1234567.1234,4));
But all of these queries insert the number 1234567,123399999920 and not  1234567,1234

Comment: Please `edit` your question and post the script there along the *wrong* result. You'll have to show other information as the NLS setting @user3621399